# Can I generate a one time use token with doorkeeper specific to one API endpoint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, doorkeeper

I am using Ruby on Rails and doorkeeper to control client auth. I am looking for a way to generate an access token that is only useful for a specific API endpoint. The goal is to send a link via email to that endpoint. I want to include the access token so they don't need to log in. However, I don't want anyone with the link to be able to log in and do whatever they want, they should only be allowed to use said endpoint with that token.
Is that possible?

Comment: I think you can JWT libaray to generate the token, while generating the token use different secret and different payload . I use to directly use jwt libraray in the doorkeeper config, but i think they have added new gem to handle jwt support. checkout this - https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-jwt

Comment: I'd prefer not having to add any additional gems, I'd rather just make the user log in and redirect them afterwards. I was just wandering if this was already possible with doorkeeper. thanks anyway

Comment: its just about having separate secrets to encode and decode the token.